# Why is my android app not compatible with most devices?

Tags: android, cordova, android-manifest

I'm building an Android `APK` from a `Cordova` project, but when I upload it to the `Play Store` it says it's only compatible with some 300 devices.

I don't know much about Android publishing; I've done this before without a problem however. If I understand correctly this should have something to do with my `AndroidManifest.xml` file, which looks like this (generated by `Cordova`):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10001" android:versionName="1.0.1" package="com.app.my" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: while using `android:supportsRtl="true"` you must set `targetSdkVersion` to 17

Comment: @Kathi He targets version 23, which is higher than 17, so this should be fine. I simply guess you meant the should increase the minSdkVersion to 17?

Comment: ohh..  
while using android:supportsRtl="true" you must set minSdkVersion to 17
thanks @Endzeit

Comment: I set the minSdkVersion to 17 and set supportsRtl to false (cause I don't actually need it, not sure why it was generated like that). Still compatibility is only for a small number of devices. So I guess it's something different than the supportsRtl?

Comment: I just changed the minSdkVersion to 14, which added a lot of devices. I have no clue as to what SDK versions are common, but I figured that 17 was pretty old since the latest SDK is already at 23. I guess not.

Comment: @Jurgen SDK 16 is Android version 4.1. Most active devices have this or a newer version. However there still are a lot of old device types that don't get updates anymore. Quite frankly you don't want to support such old devices anyway.